# Kendo UI in Export to PDF

Tags: input, kendo-ui, placeholder, export-to-pdf

Placeholder not displaying  when click export to PDF.
Placeholder not displaying for Employee Code and Employee Name.

Even though i added placeholder for Employee Code and Employee Name columns.

Please check the below link and suggest the solution.

Reference Link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWyjOR

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/page-layout">
        <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
          .pdf-page{
            padding-top:25px;
          }
          .empcode{
           margin-left:40px;margin-top:20px;
          }
          input::-moz-placeholder {
      color:  red !important;
    }
    input:-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: red !important;
    }
    input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
      color: red !important;
    } </style>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="example">
        <div class="page-container">
            <div class="pdf-page size-a4">
              <div class="empcode">
                 Employee Code:  <input data-bind="code" type="text" placeholder="Employee Code"> <input data-bind="name" type="text" placeholder="Employee Name">
              </div>
              <div class="box-col empcode">
                <h4>Get PDF</h4>
                <button class="export-pdf k-button" onclick="getPDF('.pdf-page')">Export</button>
            </div>
              <div class="empcode">
                <p>Example</p>
                <a href="http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPxrKa">http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPxrKa</div>

            </div>
        </div>


        <style>
            /*
                Use the DejaVu Sans font for display and embedding in the PDF file.
                The standard PDF fonts have no support for Unicode characters.
            */
            .pdf-page {
                font-family: "DejaVu Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            // Import DejaVu Sans font for embedding

            // NOTE: Only required if the Kendo UI stylesheets are loaded
            // from a different origin, e.g. cdn.kendostatic.com
            kendo.pdf.defineFont({
                "DejaVu Sans"             : "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans.ttf",
                "DejaVu Sans|Bold"        : "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf",
                "DejaVu Sans|Bold|Italic" : "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf",
                "DejaVu Sans|Italic"      : "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf",
                "WebComponentsIcons"      : "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/fonts/glyphs/WebComponentsIcons.ttf"
            });
        </script>

        <!-- Load Pako ZLIB library to enable PDF compression -->
        <script src="../content/shared/js/pako.min.js"></script>

        <script>
          function getPDF(selector) {
            kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(selector)).then(function(group){
              kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "Invoice.pdf");
            });
          }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var data = [
              { productName: "QUESO CABRALES", unitPrice: 21, qty: 5 },
              { productName: "ALICE MUTTON", unitPrice: 39, qty: 7 },
              { productName: "GENEN SHOUYU", unitPrice: 15.50, qty: 3 },
              { productName: "CHARTREUSE VERTE", unitPrice: 18, qty: 1 },
              { productName: "MASCARPONE FABIOLI", unitPrice: 32, qty: 2 },
              { productName: "VALKOINEN SUKLAA", unitPrice: 16.25, qty: 3 }
            ];
            var schema = {
              model: {
                productName: { type: "string" },
                unitPrice: { type: "number", editable: false },
                qty: { type: "number" }
              },
              parse: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function(){
                        this.total = this.qty * this.unitPrice;
                    });
                    return data;
              }
            };
            var aggregate = [
              { field: "qty", aggregate: "sum" },
              { field: "total", aggregate: "sum" }
            ];
            var columns = [
              { field: "productName", title: "Product", footerTemplate: "Total"},
              { field: "unitPrice", title: "Price", width: 120},
              { field: "qty", title: "Pcs.", width: 120, aggregates: ["sum"], footerTemplate: "#=sum#" },
              { field: "total", title: "Total", width: 120, aggregates: ["sum"], footerTemplate: "#=sum#" }
            ];
            var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
              editable: false,
              sortable: true,
              dataSource: {
                data: data,
                aggregate: aggregate,
                schema: schema,
              },
              columns: columns
            });

            $("#paper").kendoDropDownList({
              change: function() {
                $(".pdf-page")
                  .removeClass("size-a4")
                  .removeClass("size-letter")
                  .removeClass("size-executive")
                  .addClass(this.value());
              }
            });
        });
        </script>
        <style>
            .pdf-page {
                margin: 0 auto;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #333;
                position: relative;
            }
            .pdf-header {
                position: absolute;
                top: .5in;
                height: .6in;
                left: .5in;
                right: .5in;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
            }
            .invoice-number {
                padding-top: .17in;
                float: right;
            }
            .pdf-footer {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: .5in;
                height: .6in;
                left: .5in;
                right: .5in;
                padding-top: 10px;
                border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
                text-align: left;
                color: #787878;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
            .pdf-body {
                position: absolute;
                top: 3.7in;
                bottom: 1.2in;
                left: .5in;
                right: .5in;
            }

            .size-a4 { width: 8.3in; height: 11.7in; }
            .size-letter { width: 8.5in; height: 11in; }
            .size-executive { width: 7.25in; height: 10.5in; }

            .company-logo {
                font-size: 30px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #3aabf0;
            }
            .for {
                position: absolute;
                top: 1.5in;
                left: .5in;
                width: 2.5in;
            }
            .from {
                position: absolute;
                top: 1.5in;
                right: .5in;
                width: 2.5in;
            }
            .from p, .for p {
                color: #787878;
            }
            .signature {
                padding-top: .5in;
            }
        </style>

    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Employee code is displaying for me, see [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/eVotu)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. For me Employee Name and Code Placeholders are not displaying in downloaded pdf file. Please help me out. Click on Export see the downloaded file.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWyjOR

Comment: Oh I see, do you want the placeholder text within the text boxes to be exported (with the placeholder text ("Employee Code" and "Employee Name"))?

Comment: Flagging this as an exact duplicate of your original question [input placeholder not appearing in Kendo ui grid Export to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862826/input-placeholder-not-appearing-in-kendo-ui-grid-export-to-pdf). So let's continue discussion there.

Comment: Exactly, I want placeholder text within the text boxes in exported file. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the value of the `placeholder` and setting it as the input `value`?

```js
var empCodePlaceholder = $("#EmpCode");
console.log(empCodePlaceholder.attr('placeholder'));
empCodePlaceholder.val(empCodePlaceholder.attr('placeholder'));

var empNamePlaceholder = $("#EmpName");
console.log(empNamePlaceholder.attr('placeholder'));
empNamePlaceholder.val(empNamePlaceholder.attr('placeholder'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Employee Code:  <input id="EmpCode" data-bind="code" type="text" placeholder="Employee Code"> <input id="EmpName" data-bind="name" type="text" placeholder="Employee Name">
```

NOTE: You will need to assign an `id` to each of the inputs in order for this to work..

You can also clear down the inputs again after pdf export, so that the placeholders remain. Full [working example](http://dojo.telerik.com/eVotu/3)